# How to add new scopes in Google Console?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-developers-console

I create new service account to use Google API and Oauth 2.0 in my web app.
I need to add these scopes in Google Console:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

In old version of Google Console I had "Add scope" button, but I can't find it in new version of https://console.developers.google.com/

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Inorder to add new scopes scroll up in the same page as shown in your image, then you can see the option "edit app".

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oor6d.png)

Once you click it you will be presented with a screen like the
following image shown below.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oirim.png)

Since you wanted to add new scope just ignore the first page (i mean: scroll down, save and continue) in the second page you can manage your scopes using the "add or remove scope" option.

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHi8W.png)